# Cake php multiply Find Conditions OR /AND

Tags: cakephp, find, conditional-statements, findall

hey guys i have been struggling with this .i am a trying to select from a table using cakephp find all e.g 
i want to select all from a table where (A == 1 AND B == 2) OR (A == 2 and B == 1) with just on query 
here is my code so far

```
$conditions =  array("OR"=>
array("Message.to_to"=>$daddy["User"]["id"],
           "Message.from_from"=>$this->Auth->user("id")),
array("Message.to_to"=>$this->Auth->user("id"),
          "Message.from_from"=>$daddy["User"]["id"])
                                                       );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your expected result  (A == 1 AND B == 2) OR (A == 2 and B == 1), try nesting the 'and' conditions which are currently missing from your code.

You also need to specify the conditions parameter.

Try the following:

```
$conditions = array(
   'conditions' => array(
     "or"=> array(
            "and" => array(
                   "Message.to_to"=>$daddy["User"]["id"],
                   "Message.from_from"=>$this->Auth->user("id"),
                   ),
            "and" => array(
                   "Message.to_to"=>$this->Auth->user("id"),
                   "Message.from_from"=>$daddy["User"]["id"],
                   ),
       ),
    ),
 );
```

Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html